# A bash script to count the number of all files

Tags: linux, bash

I just started to learn linux.
What I wanna do is to write a bash script that prints the file name, the number of lines, and the number of words to stdout, for all files in the directory
for example: Apple.txt 15 155
I don't know how to write a command that can work for all the files in the directory.

Comment: have a look at the `wc` command: `man wc`

Comment: @Allen Welcome to SO. Please post what you have tried and what isn't working. As is, it's unclear what you're having issues with and is a bit too broad to fit the question guidelines. [Coder256's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37244204/3076724) works for all the (non-hidden) files in the directory, but seems like you've already tried that per your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your most recent comment, I would say you want something like:

```
wc -lw ./* | awk '{print $3 "\t" $1 "\t" $2}'
```

Note that you will get a line in the output (from stderr) for each directory that looks something like:

```
wc: ./this-is-a-directory: Is a directory
```

If the message about directories is undesirable, you can suppress stderr messages by adding `2>/dev/null` to the `wc` command, like this:

```
wc -lw ./* 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $3 "\t" $1 "\t" $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
wc -lw ./*
```

It will be in the format of `<lines> <words> <filename>`.

Comment: I tired to use this one ..  but the format i wanna get is fielname lines words